# how to add users in the sharepoint

Tags: permissions, sharepoint-designer

I am a beginner in using SharePoint. I have Microsoft Office SharePoint Designer 2007 and I want to create a simple page for me and other users on the network to share files with each other.

I have created a new web site, then I create a new folder in the folder list then drop some files into this folder.

Now, I want to invite my team to this page to view and edit these files. I heard that there is a way to invite them by E-mail.

Can you please help me with this?

Also, after I invite them -- how can they browse the page and the folder?

Answer (score 2):

As you use Sharepoint, you will have some kind of AD domain. You simply need to add your users into one of the automatically created groups `"<yoursite> members"` or `"<yoursite> visitors"` as [described in the documentation](http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/windows-sharepoint-services-help/view-users-and-sharepoint-groups-and-edit-the-quick-launch-group-list-HA010100150.aspx).

When adding users to a group, you will have the option to send a notification email with customizable text. Of course, it will only arrive if your Sharepoint installation is [correctly configured to send mail](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263462.aspx) and the users do have valid mail addresses specified with their account (LDAP "mail" field).

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with workflows you can achieve your task easily. You need to go into SharePoint designer and start creating an workflow and in that workflow just add an activity to "Send Email". Save it and publish it for your site.

Note: Make sure that the users that you want to invite are in a group and make sure to publish the workflow for "your" site.

Hope the information helps.
Thanks & Regards,
Chandra Shekhar

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the actual server, you can use powershell to add groups and/or users.  With powershell, you can add users and groups in bulk.  If you are a server administrator, powershell will help you immensely with your work.  However, if you don't have access to a console, powershell isn't going to do you much good!

I had to create 200 users, add them to various groups, and then email each one of them to tell them their username, password, and the link to the sharepoint site.  I did this with a powershell script that read the values from an excel sheet.  The script added the users to Active Directory, added the groups to Sharepoint, and then emailed everybody.

Here is a simplified email script for powershell:

```
#* ======================
#* Alert Me Script
#* ======================
#* Create Email Function
#* ======================
function sendEmail {

#* Create new .NET object and assign to variable
$mail = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage

#* Sender Address
$mail.From = "relay@sspxusa.com";

#* Recipient Address
$mail.To.Add("recipient@somewhere.com");

#* Message Subject
$mail.Subject = "Test Mail";

#* Message Body
$mail.Body = "Hey, whaz up?";

#* Connect to your mail server
$smtp = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("mail.yourserver.com");

#* Uncomment line below if authentication is required
$smtp.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("relay@yourserver.com", "yourpassword");

#* Send Email
$smtp.Send($mail);
}

#* =====================
#* Script Body
#* =====================

#* Connect to file. You can connect to a local file or a remote file via UNC.
#* In this example I connect to a remote share
$File = Get-ChildItem "c:\test.txt"

#* Check File size and take action based on condition.
if ($File.Length -gt 2000)
#* If condition is TRUE call sendEmail function
{sendEmail}

#* If condition is FALSE script does nothing
```

And here is an excellent, and quick course on how to use powershell:
http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/ebook/archive/2008/10/19/chapter-1-the-powershell-console.aspx